# Image with only two rounded corners in silverlight xaml c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, border

How I can display images in xaml with **only two** rounded corners?

```
<Image x:Name="Image" Height="200" Width="250" Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
   <Image.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Rect="0,0,250,200"/>
   </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

I want only two bottom corner round.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for your Image, and specify [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property

```
<Grid>
    <Border Height="200" Width="250" CornerRadius="0,0,50,50">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Desert.jpg" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And use image as background brush

Here is example with this xaml. Just change ImageSource

[image]

Comment: When I put bigger CornerRadius="0,0,50,50" and I also don' wont BorderThickness

Comment: it's okey, and very simle...  Thanks