# How to mask a square image into an image with round corners?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

As i want to implement a **Rounded Cornered Mask** to my  **Image control** i Designed a control like this

```
    <Border x:Name="Border1"  CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
            <Image  x:Name="ImageSource1" Background="Transparent" >
            </Image>
    </Border> 
<Border x:Name="MaskBorder1"  BorderBrush="White"  CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="3" />
```

But am getting an **Control** with .

[image]

Anybody have an idea to fill up corners with the **Border Color** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just clip the Image, here is a snippet I use

```
 <Image                               
                            Width="96"
                            Height="96"
                            Stretch="UniformToFill"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Image.Clip>
                                <EllipseGeometry
                                    Center="48,48"
                                    RadiusX="48"
                                    RadiusY="48" />
                            </Image.Clip>
                        </Image>
```

To make it work, you need to set Center, RadiusX and RadiusY to half the image size.

Comment: This won't work on Windows Phone 8.1 (RT), as it only supports rectangular clipping

Answer (score 2):

Don't know it this could help? But for image manipulations I always us the [Writeablebitmapex library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)!
And a good example on masking images can be found [here...](http://adamkinney.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/image-blitting-in-silverlight-with-writeablebitmapex/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your use of `CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius,Mode=TwoWay}"` but I would be interested in seeing your implementation, after checking out [Stecya's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801525/image-with-only-two-rounded-corners-in-silverlight-xaml-c-sharp) should it prove to be what you are looking for.