# How to set rounded corners for an image control?

Tags: image, button, controls, windows-phone-8, rounded-corners

### Background

I'm a noob on Windows Phone 8. I've learnt WPF and Silverlight in the past, but it was long ago.

On Windows phone 8, I have a clickable Image control which I wish to have its content (the picture itself) to have rounded corners.

### The question

How do I set rounded corners to a control?

Also, I might consider having a Button control instead, so that I could customize what happens when it is being clicked (or touched). Upon clicking, I would like that the area that has the rounded corners would be colored in some color, showing that it was indeed being clicked/touched. How do I do that?

---

EDIT:

Thanks to @Depechie, I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801561/878126):

```
<Grid>
    <Border Height="200" Width="250" CornerRadius="0,0,50,50">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Desert.jpg" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

However, I have two problems with that:

1. I still can't find how to make it seen as clicked when you touch it, so that the rounded corners would have a yellow background.
2. I can't get the imageSource and the converter (and its parameter) via code when handling the clicking event. Previously, I've used:

   Image thumbnailImage = (Image)sender;
   var bindingExpression = thumbnailImage.GetBindingExpression(Image.SourceProperty);
   string selectedItem = (string)bindingExpression.DataItem;
   string selectedThumbnailIndex = (string)  bindingExpression.ParentBinding. ConverterParameter;

   Maybe I could create the items programmatically instead of Xaml? If so, how (items are in a grid, btw)?

What can I do now?

Answer (score 4):

Try this by using Rect

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Stretch="None" 
                       Source="Jellyfish.jpg">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="5"
                                           RadiusY="5"
                                           Rect="0,0,150,113"/>
                    </Image.Clip>
                </Image>
```

Here is the another link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750631(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question listed [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598375/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners/)
Maybe those can help you too?

And if you want to have the ilusion that the image is a clickable control, take a look at [TiltEffect](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/using-tilteffect-in-wp7) that is available in [the Phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but i still have some problems with this. please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to alter the shape of a control (Which after looking in VS and Blend I dont think is possible) Why not simply create your image with rounded edges and then set the button border and background to no color?

Comment: For 2 reasons : images can stretch (including the rounded corners) and won't look well on different screens. Images can be downloaded from the internet and not available within the app. I don't even know if WP8 supports 9-patch images in order to overcome stretching of the corners.

Answer (score 0):

For the rounded corners, you can set the RadiusX and RadiusY values to nonzero numbers to achieve that effect in a rectangle. So I imagine you could embed a button inside the rectangle if you want to keep the button control.

Comment: Please put a snippet. I'm a noob at WP8 , and i've tried some solutions and for some reason they didn't work for me. Also, please tell me how to set the pressed-state to be shown with a color on the rounded corners. I think i need to use ControlTemplate or ContentPresenter or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image  Width="25" Height="25"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Stretch="Fill" 
                        >
                                                        <Image.Clip>
                                                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="12.5"
                                           RadiusY="12.5"
                                           Rect="0,0,25,25"/>
                                                        </Image.Clip>
                                                    </Image>
```

The corner radius should be half of width or height.